# Why defaultdict constructor takes a function and not a constant

Tags: python, collections

This is how defaultdict works:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a=defaultdict(lambda:3)
a[200]==3 #True
```

**Why is it that `defaultdict` was designed to take a function with no arguments, and not simply a constant value?**

---

Here's the alternative definition.

```
class dd(dict):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self._default=x
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if key in self: return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        else:
            self[key]=self._default
            return self[key]
```

So that

```
a=dd(3)
a[200]==3 #True
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because if you want the default value to be a mutable object, you probably want it to be a different mutable object for each key.

If you passed a constant and did `defaultdict([])`, then every time a missing key was accessed, its value would be set to the same list.  Then you'd get this:

```
>>> d = defaultdict([])
>>> d[1].append("Whoops")
>>> print d[2]
["Whoops"]
```

Having a mutable default value is in fact very common and useful, since it lets you do things like `d[key].append("Blah")` without having to first check that `d[key]` exists.  For this case, you need some way to return a new value each time, and the simplest way to do that is to have a callable that returns a default value.

Comment: Agreed. Follow-up question... if it had to be a function, then wouldn't it have made more useful to have the function optionally take the key as an input? E.g. ``defaultdict(lambda x:x+1)`` could return ``201`` for ``a[200]``.

Comment: @KalEl: I've often wished for that as well.  I would guess that one reason that wasn't done is that there's no clean way for the caller to know whether the function wants that argument or no arguments.  For the common case where the "function" is `list` or `dict`, you can't pass a (non-iterable) argument, which means we got stuck with no argument.  You can write your own class that works that way, but yeah, I do wish `defaultdict` did it.